# I get an error: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Inflater has been closed" when sending requests using requests 2.8.1 in Jython 2.7

Tags: python, jython, jython-2.7

My code:

```
from Core.PythonLib import requests
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
def go_url(self, url, data=None, headers={}):
    if data:
        send = requests.post
    else:
        send = requests.get

    response = send(url, data=data, headers=headers, auth=(self.username, self.password))
    response.raise_for_status()
    print response.status_code
    print response.content
```

I send two requests at first I get an answer, and in the second I fall error:

first:

```
Set state
200
{"status":"ok", ..... .....}
Loading admin SAVE from file [Empty] - Success!
```

Second:

```
TEST_ERROR: 
  File "D:\autotest\Core\Admin.py", line 94, in go_url
    response = send(url, data=data, headers=headers, auth=(self.username, self.password))

  File "D:\autotest\Core\PythonLib\requests\api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)

  File "D:\autotest\Core\PythonLib\requests\api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

  File "D:\autotest\Core\PythonLib\requests\sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

  File "D:\autotest\Core\PythonLib\requests\sessions.py", line 597, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []

  File "D:\autotest\Core\PythonLib\requests\sessions.py", line 187, in resolve_redirects
    resp = self.send(

  File "D:\autotest\Core\PythonLib\requests\sessions.py", line 608, in send
    r.content

  File "D:\autotest\Core\PythonLib\requests\models.py", line 734, in content
    self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()

  File "D:\autotest\Core\PythonLib\requests\models.py", line 734, in content
    self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()

  File "D:\autotest\Core\PythonLib\requests\models.py", line 657, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):

  File "D:\autotest\Core\PythonLib\requests\models.py", line 657, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):

  File "D:\autotest\Core\PythonLib\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 322, in stream
    for line in self.read_chunked(amt, decode_content=decode_content):

  File "D:\autotest\Core\PythonLib\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 471, in read_chunked
    yield self._decode(chunk, decode_content=decode_content,

  File "D:\autotest\Core\PythonLib\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 190, in _decode
    data = self._decoder.decompress(data)

  File "D:\autotest\Core\PythonLib\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 190, in _decode
    data = self._decoder.decompress(data)

  File "D:\autotest\Core\PythonLib\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 56, in decompress
    return self._obj.decompress(data)

  File "D:\autotest\SikuliX\sikulix.jar\Lib\zlib.py", line 155, in decompress
    inflated = _get_inflate_data(self.inflater, max_length)

  File "D:\autotest\SikuliX\sikulix.jar\Lib\zlib.py", line 202, in _get_inflate_data
    l = inflater.inflate(buf)

  File "D:\autotest\SikuliX\sikulix.jar\Lib\zlib.py", line 202, in _get_inflate_data
    l = inflater.inflate(buf)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Inflater has been closed
```

If the request to specify the flag: **"stream=True"** the request fulfills but then I can not do: **print response.content**, it issued the same error!
Someone may be faced with such a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. You need to upgrade your requests library.
requests-2.11.1 works for me. Hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely try the new version. At the time when was the issue, was not yet this version. But I still think the problem is somewhere in Jython 2.7. I сould be wrong.